# How to report on opportunities from a date field on the account?

Tags: reporting

I have a custom fate field on the account: **Date_Field__c**

I want to report on all opptys, from that account, where the `close_date > Date_Field__c`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a formula for that. Basically, a formula on the account object that returns true if that condition is true. This is because you can't compare two different fields in the report filter criteria.

Fields > New > Formula > Checkbox

```
close_date > Date_Field__c
```

You can also vote for this idea :)

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrHAAA0

Comment: definitely voted on the idea. Can you please elaborate bit more on the way to achieve this with formulas?

Comment: @Saariko I have updated my answer.